# How to debug Ant project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ant

This kind of question may be asked before, but I could not find my case among them.

I am working on Web application based on Ant build which is running on Tomcat 6.

My normal process to deploy the application on server is:

Copy the project files on tomcat/webapps/

or

Copy the war file to tomcat/webapps and deploy.

Now the question is how I can perform server-side debug in my project with Eclipse. I have tried to add project in the Eclipse tomcat server instance but it is not showing my project available to add in server.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information, in order to get a good answer. A common way to import a project into Eclipse is this:

1. New -> Import -> Existing Project or(!) Filesystem
2. Check if it is a "Dynamic Web Project": right click project name -> Properties -> Project Facets -> choose Java 1.6/1.7/1.8 and Servlet 3.0.
3. Open Ant view: Window -> Views -> Others -> Ant
4. Drag your ant scripts in to this view.
5. Open Servers view: Window -> Views -> Others -> Servers
6. Create a new server, right clicking this view.
7. Add the project to the newly created server.

Answer (score 0):

add below xml tag to ant `build.xml` after target init

```
<javac srcdir="${src.java.dir}" destdir="${target.build.dir}" includeantruntime="true" source="${source}" target="${target}" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" classpathref="main.classpath" fork="true" memoryinitialsize="512m" memorymaximumsize="512m" />
```

make sure to add `debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source"` to have a interactive debug session.